# Find duplicate columns that have values that end with same last four digits - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, records

I need a query that will search for all records in a table and return only the ones that have 2 or more values that end with same 4 digits, but i dont have specific four digits i can give you, i just need it to find everything that has more than one value that ends the same. 
eg. table has:

```
person_number------------name
==============================
1234567------------------john 
00004567-----------------mark
9999999------------------mike
0009999------------------lidia
10101010-----------------alex
23232323-----------------matt
98748484-----------------steve
```

I want it to return only:

```
person_number------------name
==============================
1234567------------------john 
00004567-----------------mark
9999999------------------mike
0009999------------------lidia
```

You see, i want it to return duplicates that end with the same last 4 digits, but i dont have specific digits to give you so i cant use something like '%9999'. It also needs to be sorted properly so I have them next to each other. I need to find duplicates and delete one of them, but i dont know which one until i actually see all the other values in other columns and pick which one to delete manually.

Thanks!

Comment: do a row_count based on the right( [PersonNumber],4)  with a rownumber > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want extend Sick answer.

You say you will like to choose which one to eliminate. But you can also include a `ORDER` clausule with a `CASE` statment to filter the one you want eliminate.

In this case I order by `"name"` so you can delete all with `rn > 1` and keep the first name.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6a34/3)**

```
select "person_number", "name", rn, zero_count
from
(
  select "person_number", 
         "name", 
         substr("person_number", 1, 1),
         count(1) over (partition by substr("person_number",-4)) as Cnt,
         SUM(case 
             when substr("person_number", 1, 1)  = '0' then 1
             else 0 end) over (partition by substr("person_number",-4)) as zero_count,
          row_number() over (partition by substr("person_number",-4) order by "name") as rn
  from person
)
Where Cnt > 1
and zero_count > 0
ORDER BY substr("person_number",-4)
```

I increase the data sample

- now include a field `zero_count` to calculate how many rows start with `0` in each group
- case where both row have same 4 char at the end and also start with 0 (`ZERO_COUNT = 2`)
- case when a row without match also start with 0

Comment: This is almost what i need but it is returning too many results, it needs some narrowing down. What needs to be added as a condition is that one of those values in the person_number column starts with 0. So: one starts with zero, but they both have last 4 digits the same. eg 011112345 and 8888888882345. Additionally I would like for this to display all columns since this table has about 50 different columns, but that is not my priority because i can add the columns in the script manually.

Comment: @Aleks That is the only additional requirement? Because Im afraid you will continue adding rules after each try

Comment: I am sorry Juan, but i think this will be it. I have duplicate records where one starts with 0 but another one does not, so i have to remove one of those rows after i look at them. So yes i think these will be only requirements.

Comment: You want remove the ones with 0?

Comment: i wont know until i see the records. With some of them i have to remove the one with zero, with others i have to remove the ones without zero, then strip the zero from the first one and commit.

Comment: I add a column zero_count, try and let me know

Comment: now when I run:
select "PERSON_NUMBER", "FIRST_NAME", rn
from
(
  select p.*, 
         count(1) over (partition by substr("PERSON_NUMBER",-4)) as Cnt,
         SUM(case 
             when substr("PERSON_NUMBER", 1)  = 0 then 1
             else 0 end) over (partition by substr("PERSON_NUMBER",-4)) as zero_count,
         row_number() over (partition by substr("PERSON_NUMBER",-4) order by "PERSON_NUMBER") as rn
  from IDW_CARD p
)
Where Cnt > 1
and zero_count > 0;

Comment: I get this error: 
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: BTW PERSON_NUMBER column is data type VARCHAR2(22 BYTE)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select person_number,name
from
(
    select person_number,name,count(1)over(partition by right(person_number,4)) as Cnt
    from YourTable
)
Where Cnt > 1
```