# finding highest count of same last digits in multiple colums

Tags: sql

I need to count how many times a duplicate value of a last digit exists between different columns. I am interested in the highest count.

```
    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
    ----   ----   ----   ----   ---- 
     1       13    23      21    31    = result should be 3 for 3 time the 1.
```

Hope that makes sense.

Any ideas if that is possible with SQL?

Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: So the query should return `3` for this row, but it will return as many values for as many rows as are in the table? And are there only 5 cols?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate columns that have values that end with same last four digits - SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529698/find-duplicate-columns-that-have-values-that-end-with-same-last-four-digits-sq)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, the table has multiple rows, the query needs to evaluate each row individually. this table has actually 6 columns, but only these 5 need to be evaluated.

Comment: Do the columns have a primary key?  Is that the 6th column? (I may have a solution, but it requires a primary key.)

Comment: no, the 6th column is a "flag" column. currently there is no key - but that doesn't mean i can't add one :-).

Comment: @Gunnar Okay, took a few edits, but that should do it.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have a solution assuming there's a primary key:

```
SELECT id, MAX(count) FROM (
    SELECT id, val, COUNT(*) AS count FROM (
        SELECT id, MOD(col1, 10) AS val FROM your_table
        UNION ALL SELECT id, MOD(col2, 10) AS val FROM your_table
        UNION ALL SELECT id, MOD(col3, 10) AS val FROM your_table
        UNION ALL SELECT id, MOD(col4, 10) AS val FROM your_table
        UNION ALL SELECT id, MOD(col5, 10) AS val FROM your_table) vals
    GROUP BY id, val) counts
GROUP BY id;
```

Note the the functions are specific to mysql, but similar functions should exist in just about any other db.

Innermost SELECT builds a derived table with id and val columns where val is the last digit from each column.  Next SELECT out from that counts each value by id.  Outermost SELECT returns the max value count by id.

And then if you're looking to display the result next to the column values, you would just join this query against the original table:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, max_count
  FROM your_table yt
       JOIN (
SELECT id, MAX(count) max_count FROM (
    SELECT id, val, COUNT(*) AS count FROM (
        SELECT id, MOD(col1, 10) AS val FROM your_table
        UNION ALL SELECT id, MOD(col2, 10) AS val FROM your_table
        UNION ALL SELECT id, MOD(col3, 10) AS val FROM your_table
        UNION ALL SELECT id, MOD(col4, 10) AS val FROM your_table
        UNION ALL SELECT id, MOD(col5, 10) AS val FROM your_table) vals
    GROUP BY id, val) counts
GROUP BY id) mc ON yt.id = mc.id;
```

Here's the output:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+-----------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | max_count |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----------+
|    1 |   13 |   23 |   21 |   31 |         3 |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----------+
```

Comment: hmm, don't think its working. I create a identify primary key column ID. I had to modify your query work in my environment (maybe i made a mistake there?). the result i am getting are rows with the ID (the key index) and another column with a 1. the 1 is in all rows. (having trouble posting the modified code)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I had to make a few changes.  Try it now.  UNION vs UNION ALL is apparently very important.  :)  UNION by itself deletes all of the duplicates which is why you were getting the 1.

Comment: BINGO, NICE !!!! that worked and is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much for your help! (i am new to this forum - is clicking the check-mark next to  your answer the correct way to give you the credit?)

Comment: @Gunnar Yep, that gave me credit.  Glad I could help.  That was actually kind of a fun one to solve.

Comment: I know straight forward SQL coding, but nothing fancy like this. I might have a few more in the next few days similar to this, but i'll give it a shot first. in the past i always just coded this in the actual app (vb.net). but i figure that doing it the sql way is much cleaner and faster.

Comment: Yeah, being able to create a derived table in the middle of a sql command that doesn't actually exist in your database is a pretty powerful little trick.  As far as whether it's much cleaner and faster, you will probably find as many opinions on that as developers you ask.  :)  Either can be an acceptable choice.